# DCG in Prolog — strings

Tags: parsing, lisp, prolog, grammar, dcg

I'm writing a Lisp-to-C translator using Prolog's built-in DCG capabilities. This is how I handle arithmetic:

```
expr(Z) --> "(", "+", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%d + %d", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "-", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%d - %d", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "*", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%d * %d", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "/", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%d / %d", [M, N])}.
expr(E) --> number(E).

number(C) --> "-", digits(X), {C is -X}.
number(C) --> digits(C).
digits(D) --> digit(D);digit(A),digits(B), {number_codes(B,Cs),length(Cs,L), D is A*(10^L)+B}.
digit(D) --> [C], {"0"=<C, C=<"9", D is C - "0"}.
```

As it is now, it doesn't handle nested expressions. Here is what I thought would work:

```
expr(Z) --> "(", "+", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%s + %s", [M, N])}.
expr(E) --> number(N), {swritef(E, "%d", [N])}.
```

But I'm getting this:

```
?- expr(E, "42", []).
E = "42" %all OK

?- expr(E, "(+ 3 (* 2 2))", []).
E = "%s + %s" %not OK
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: @Bobby: SWI-Prolog version 5.6.64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the %s format specifier needs the argument to be a list of characters.
So you can do it with something like this:

```
:-set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).  % This is for SWI 7+ to revert to the prior interpretation of quoted strings.

expr(Z) --> "(", "+", spaces, lexpr(M), spaces, lexpr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%s + %s", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "-", spaces, lexpr(M), spaces, lexpr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%s - %s", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "*", spaces, lexpr(M), spaces, lexpr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%s * %s", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "/", spaces, lexpr(M), spaces, lexpr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "%s / %s", [M, N])}.
expr(N) --> number(N).

lexpr(Z) --> expr(M), {atom_chars(M, Z)}.

number(C) --> "-", digits(X), {C is -X}.
number(C) --> digits(C).

digits(D) --> digit(D);digit(A),digits(B), {number_codes(B,Cs),length(Cs,L), D is A*(10^L)+B}.
digit(D) --> [C], {"0"=<C, C=<"9", D is C - "0"}.

spaces --> " ", spaces.
spaces --> [].
```

The predicate lexpr just converts the parsed expression to a list of chars.

**Edit: 03/07/2016:** As of SWI version 7.0, text enclosed in double quotes are not interpreted as a list of character codes anymore.
You can either change double quotes with back quotes (`) or add a directive ;

`:-set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).`

at the beginning of the code.

Comment: This demo seems to be incompatible with SWI-Prolog. Which version of Prolog should I use to run it?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: In SWI starting at version 7, text between double quotes are, by default, not being interpreted as a list of character codes. I've edited the answer to show which prolog flag should be turned on for the code to work. Alternative you may change the double quotes with back quotes (`)

Answer (score 1):

Use [%t or %w, not %d](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=writef%2f2) in your `swritef`. Note, %d is not what it is in C's printf formats.

If you just translating lisp-like to C-like you don't really need to convert the string
representation of numbers to a number. Just leave it as string. (Of course it dependes
on the complexity of your task). Otherwise the upper level rules foound a number where they expect a string.

Put the resultant C code into parentheses so that the priority and associativity are correct in the result.

```
expr(Z) --> "(", "-", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "(%t - %t)", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "*", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "(%t * %t)", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "/", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "(%t / %t)", [M, N])}.
expr(Z) --> "(", "+", spaces, expr(M), spaces, expr(N), ")", {swritef(Z, "(%t + %t)", [M, N])}.
expr(E) --> number(N), {swritef(E, "%s", [N])}.

spaces --> " ".

number([C|Cs]) --> "-", {C = "-"}, digits(Cs).
number(C) --> digits(C).

digits([D|[]]) --> digit(D).

digits([D|Ds]) --> digit(D), digits(Ds).
digit(D) --> [D], {code_type(D, digit)}.
```

and this is how it works.

```
?- expr(E, "(* 1342 (/ 44 -17))", []).
E = "(1342 * (44 / -17))" ;
false.
```

Comment: I ran this demo in SWI-Prolog, but it only printed `E = "(%t * %t)" .` Which version of Prolog should I use to run this example?